# I cannot submit a new Employee succesfully in React form

Tags: java, reactjs, typescript, spring, react-fullstack

I am new in the full stack develoment. I have a full stack project with Java Spring boot for the backend and React Typescript for the backend.I have created two entities, Company and Employee.

The entities in the backend:

```
//For employee:
//domain
   @Data
   public class EmployeeDTO implements Serializable {

    Long id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    String name;

    @Size(max = 255)
    String surName;

    @Size(max = 255)
    String email;

    LocalDate startDate;

    Integer vacationDays;

    Double salary;

    @Size(max = 20)
    String employmentType;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CompanyDTO employeeCompany;
}

//service
   @Transactional
       public EmployeeDTO save(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO){
           log.debug("Request to save Company : {}",employeeDTO);
           Employee employee = employeeMapper.toEntity(employeeDTO);
           employee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
           return employeeMapper.toDto(employee);
       }

//controller
   @PostMapping("/employee")
       public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> createEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO){
           log.debug("Rest request to save Company : {}",employeeDTO);
           EmployeeDTO result = employeeService.save(employeeDTO);
           return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
       }


//For the company:

//domain
   @Data
   public class CompanyDTO implements Serializable {
       Long id;

       @NotNull
       @Size(max = 255)
       String name;

       @NotNull
       @Size(max = 255)
       String address;

       @NotNull
       @Size(max = 10, min = 10)
       String phone;
}

//service
   @Transactional
       public CompanyDTO save(CompanyDTO companyDTO){
           log.debug("Request to save Company : {}",companyDTO);
           Company company = companyMapper.toEntity(companyDTO);
           company = companyRepository.save(company);
           return companyMapper.toDto(company);
       }

//controller
   @CrossOrigin
       @PostMapping("/newcompany")
       public ResponseEntity<CompanyDTO> save(@RequestBody CompanyDTO companyDTO){
           log.debug("Rest request to save Company : {}",companyDTO);
           CompanyDTO result = companyService.save(companyDTO);
           return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.CREATED);
       }
```

Now i will give you for the frontend part with React Typescript:

```
//For company:
   //model
   export interface CompanyDTO {
     id?: number;
     name?: string;
     address?: string;
     phone?: string;
   }

    //create new company form
   import * as yup from "yup";
   import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
   import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
   import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
   import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
   import { Box, Button } from "@mui/material";
   import MuiTextField from "../../components/MuiTextField";
   import axios from "axios";
   import { toast, ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

    // create schema validation
   export const CompanySchema = yup.object({
     id: yup.string().required("id is required"),
     name: yup.string().required("name is required"),
     address: yup.string().required("address is required"),
     phone: yup.string().required("phone is required"),
   });

   const CompanyForm = () => {
     const params = useParams();
     const navigate = useNavigate();

     useEffect(() => {
       if (params && params?.id) {
         axios
           .get(`http://localhost:8081/api/company/${params?.id}`)
           .then((response) => {
             reset(response.data);
           })
           .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
      }, []);

      const {
        handleSubmit,
        reset,
        formState: { errors },
        control,
      } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
          id: "",
          name: "",
          address: "",
          phone: "",
        },
        resolver: yupResolver(CompanySchema),
      });

      const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
        if (!params?.id) {
          
          fetch("http://localhost:8081/api/newcompany", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
          })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
              navigate(`/company/${data?.id}`);
              toast.success("created!");
            });
        } else {
          // update
          fetch(`http://localhost:8081/api/updatecompany/${params?.id}`, {
            method: "PUT" /* or PATCH */,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
          })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(() => {
              console.log("test");
              toast.info("updated!");
            });
        }
      };

      return (
        <div>
          <Button onClick={() => navigate(-1)} variant="outlined">Back</Button>
          <h1>Company Form</h1>
          <Box
            sx={{
             width: "200px",
            }}
          >
            <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <MuiTextField
                errors={errors}
                control={control}
                name="id"
                label="ID"
              />
             <MuiTextField
                errors={errors}
                control={control}
                name="name"
                label="NAME"
              />
              <MuiTextField
                errors={errors}
                control={control}
                name="address"
                label="ADDRESS"
              />
              <MuiTextField
                 errors={errors}
                 control={control}
                 name="phone"
                 label="PHONE"
             />
             <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="outlined"
                sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
             >
                Submit
             </Button>
            </form>
          </Box>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default CompanyForm;


    //for the employee:
    //model
    import {CompanyDTO} from "../company/company.model";
    export interface EmployeeDTO {
        id?: number;
        name?: string;
        surName?: string;
        email?: string;
        startDate?: Date;
        vacationDays?: number;
        salary?: number;
        employmentType?: string;
        employeeCompany?: CompanyDTO;

    }

    //create a new employee form
    import * as yup from "yup";
    import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
    import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
    import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import { Box, Button } from "@mui/material";
    import MuiTextField from "../../components/MuiTextField";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { toast } from "react-toastify";
    import { CompanySchema } from "../company/CompanyForm";

    // create schema validation
    export const EmployeeSchema = yup.object({
        //id: yup.number().required("id is required"),
        name: yup.string().required("name is required"),
        surName: yup.string().required("surname is required"),
        email: yup.string().required("email is required"),
        startDate: yup.date().required("Start Date is required"),
        vacationDays: yup.number().required("Vacation days are required"),
        salary: yup.number().required("Salary is required"),
        employmentType: yup.string().required("Employment type is required"),
        employeeCompany: CompanySchema.required("Employee Company is required"),
    });

    const EmployeeForm = () => {
       const params = useParams();
       const navigate = useNavigate();

       useEffect(() => {
           if (params && params?.id) {
               axios
                   .get(`http://localhost:8081/api/employee/${params?.id}`)
                   .then((response) => {
                        reset(response.data);
                   })
                    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
            }
        }, []);

       const {
            handleSubmit,
            reset,
            formState: { errors },
            control,
        } = useForm({
            defaultValues: {
                id: "",
                name: "",
                surName: "",
                email: "",
                startDate: "",
                vacationDays: "",
                salary: "",
                employmentType: "",
                employeeCompany: {id: ""},
            },
            resolver: yupResolver(EmployeeSchema),
         });

        const onSubmit = (data: any) => {

            if (!params?.id) {

                //if it is a new record we post it
                fetch("http://localhost:8081/api/employee", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json',"Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        console.log(data);
                        navigate(`/employee/${data?.id}`);
                        toast.success("created!");
                    });
            } else {
                console.log("updating form data:", data);
                // else we make an update
                fetch(`http://localhost:8081/api/updateemployee/${params?.id}`, {
                    method: "PUT" /* or PATCH */,
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                })
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log("test");
                        toast.info("updated!");
                    });
            }
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={() => navigate(-1)} variant="outlined">Back</Button>
                <h1>Employee Form</h1>
                <Box
                    sx={{
                        width: "200px",
                    }}
                >
                    <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                         <MuiTextField
                            errors={errors}
                            control={control}
                            name="name"
                            label="NAME"
                         />
                         <MuiTextField
                            errors={errors}
                            control={control}
                            name="surName"
                            label="SURNAME"
                        />
                        <MuiTextField
                            errors={errors}
                            control={control}
                            name="email"
                            label="EMAIL"
                        />
                        <MuiTextField
                            errors={errors}
                            control={control}
                            name="startDate"
                            label="STARTDATE"
                        />
                        <MuiTextField
                            errors={errors}
                            control={control}
                            name="vacationDays"
                            label="VACATION DAYS"
                        />
                        <MuiTextField
                            errors={errors}
                            control={control}
                            name="salary"
                            label="SALARY"
                        />
                        <MuiTextField
                            errors={errors}
                            control={control}
                            name="employmentType"
                            label="EMPLOYMENT TYPE"
                        />
                        <MuiTextField
                            errors={errors}
                            control={control}
                            name="employeeCompany.id"
                            label="Employee Company"
                        />
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            
                            fullWidth
                            variant="outlined"
                            sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                 </Box>
             </div>
         );
    };

    export default EmployeeForm;
```

I can submit succesfully a new company record from the company form in React. But the problem is on the employee form. When i'm submitting a new employee it does not do anything. I searched that the cause would be serialize and deserialize the entities. Also, expect dtos i've created and normal entities. Does anyone know what can i do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot in the dark, as the full set of APIs is not provided. But assuming it is inline with the company URL design, you should change the POST URL to `/newemployee` instead of `/employee` in the `onSubmit` of your `EmployeeForm`.